# Why `Box-shadow` Is not displayed at the bottom in IE11?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-11, box-shadow

I added box-shadow using pseudo selector to a `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;` element it's working in chrome and safari but in IE11 it get floats to the right side not the bottom, I think its because of `flex-flow: row wrap;`. any thoughts on whats goin on?

[image: Chrome screenshot]

[image: IE11 Screenshot]

```css
.main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.hero-image {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-image::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 50px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 50px #000;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.div--1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.div--2 {
  background-color: #333d47;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="div--1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300?image=0" />
    </div>
    <div class="div--2">some text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow is over the image:

```css
.main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.hero-image {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.div--1::after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(#000));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, #000 100%);
  margin-top: -120px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}

.div--1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.div--2 {
  background-color: #333d47;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="div--1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300?image=0" />
    </div>
    <div class="div--2">some text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a `top: 0;` on `.hero-image::after`. Otherwise the shadow will be pulled down by the text and the image.

```css
.main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.hero-image {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-image::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 50px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 50px #000;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.div--1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.div--2 {
  background-color: #333d47;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="div--1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300?image=0" />
    </div>
    <div class="div--2">some text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn’t get it then. How do you want it to be?

Comment: I figured it out, I really appreciate your help tho. I added the shadow to the `div--1` and `position: relative` . check the answer I will post